# Cannot ping 2012 R2 host server from external addresses after installing Hyper-V

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v, ping

Development box running 2012 R2, Ubuntu 16.04 in a Hyper-V VM

Port forwarding set up on internet-facing router to pass through to host server.

Can RDP into the host server just fine.

Can ping to/from host server and VM within network using local IP (firewall rules are configured correctly).

Can ping to host server using host external IP from Ubuntu VM and other machines on the internal network.

Cannot ping host server from any external IP (tried from multiple locations).

Host responded to ping just fine before configuring hyper-v install (virtual switch is set as external). Every other thing networking-related works just fine from host, VM, all other boxes on the network.

Have tried double checking all firewall rules, changing adapter binding order in advanced network settings, rebooting, everything else that seemed obvious.

It's a really minor thing, especially as RDP and everything else works just fine. But if anyone has any suggestions as to what might be causing this and/or how to fix it I would appreciate the input, as sometimes I just want to ping the server instead of logging into it.

Comment: If all other connectivity is fine why are you concerned about whether or not you can ping the host? Why does it matter? Why do you care? Sometimes you just want to ping the Server? For what purpose? What value is in doing that?

Comment: Because the server is headless and non-trivial to get to and hook up a monitor to. If it responds to ping or not is a useful diagnostic if something else is going wrong. If other services are not responding but it responds to ping I can start to figure out what's wrong.